# Ubuntu 15.10. Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization

Tags: apparmor

I recently updated to Ubuntu 15.10.  I am now getting a failed boot with the following message:

Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization

How can I further diagnose and fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to boot in recovery mode, and then select the recover option.

I have no idea why the problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I installed SELinux and apparmor while it is not a good idea.
Ubuntu didn't even start after trying to uninstall it.

this is what I did to fix my problem:

1. first uninstall everything:

   ```
   sudo apt remove selinux apparmor
   sudo apt purge --autoremove selinux apparmor
   ```
2. then edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and change `selinux` parts with `apparmor`.
3. reinstall apparmor `sudo apt install apparmor`
4. if your lucky it will work. if not then reboot to recovery mode and choose `grub` option (update grub bootloader)

after this some of your apps may not work (if you installed `apparmor-profiles`) then you can just use `aa-complain [app]` to fix it.

thanks.